# best way to call a method of a class to change location tkinter python classes

Tags: python, class, methods, tkinter

I have the following code which seeks to create 2 more instances of the Ball class, of different colours and at different locations. Currently the method that creates the oval and specifies its position is in the **init** method.

**Problem:** I have tried to create ball2 and ball3 (creating instances of the class Ball) but they haven't worked. They overwrite ball1, for obvious reasons.

I am after some suggestions for the best solution with an answer (code)

Is it best to call the method directly from where it is now, and if so how? (I have tried various things which didn't work).

Else, is it more pythonic or efficient to create a new method to draw the ball, and if so, could you provide this as an answer.

An answer would ideally contain both the above, along with explanation or any other alternatives, if any.

**Code below**

```
class Ball: #create a ball class
    def __init__(self,canvas,color): #initiliased with the variables/attributes self, canvas, and color
        self.canvas=canvas #set the intiial values for the starting attributes
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(30,30,50,50,fill=color) #starting default values for the ball
        """ Note: x and y coordinates for top left corner and x and y coordinates for the bottom right corner, and finally the fill colour for the oval
        """
        self.canvas.move(self.id,0,0) #thia moves the oval to the specified location

    def draw(self): #we have created the draw method but it doesn't do anything yet.
        pass 


ball1=Ball(canvas,'green') #here we are creating an object (green ball) of the class Ball

ball2=Ball(canvas,'blue')
ball3=Ball(canvas,'purple')
```

For instance, to try and move it into a method I tried this, but with no luck:

```
 def moveball(x_position,y_position):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,0,0)


ball3=Ball(canvas,'purple')
ball3.moveball(100,100)
```

**Error:**

```
    ball3.moveball(100,100)
TypeError: moveball() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are trying to solve here? Please see http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I've edited the question to include the problem more clearly. The balls2 and ball3 (instances) overwrite ball1. I am after a solution to that problem in the most efficient way - either to call the attribute in the __init__ class or to fix my attempt at creating another method, which doesn't work (see edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this, which does work. Obviously will wait to see if anyone comes up with anything better or more efficient.

**Create the following method:**

```
def move(self,x,y): #we have created the draw method but it doesn't do anything yet.
        canvas.move(self.id,x,y)
```

**Call ball3 like so:**

ball3.move(100,200)

This produces another ball to the screen in another location, as the question requests.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your error you need to add `self` as an argument for `moveball`, if it is within your ball class. (This would need to be the first argument)

Your balls do not 'overwrite' each other, they just appear over each other on the canvas in the order you create them.

You could prevent this by either moving them after creation (specify an x and y amount) or by passing initial coordinates (x1, y1, x2, y2 or x, y and then using an offset).